# Trying to retrieve data froman XMl file but I get the error as file is in use

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Xml. I'm a newbie into programming so please pardon me.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    string MyXmlFile= @"E:\\Programming stuff\\Work\\website\\XMLFile.xml";    
     DataSet ds= new DataSet();

    System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml= new System.IO.FileStream(MyXmlFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

    ds.ReadXml(MyReadXml);

    DataGrid DataGrid1 = new DataGrid();

    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
   }
```

The error I get on the browser is:

"The process cannot access the file 'E:\Programming stuff\Work\website\XMLFile.xml' because it is being used by another process."

Can you help me identify which is that other process that is accessing the file?

Edit: After the changes to the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack) 
  {
    string MyXmlFile= Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml");    


   using(System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml= new System.IO.FileStream(MyXmlFile,System.IO.FileMode.Open));
    {
 DataSet ds= new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(MyReadXml);

DataGrid DataGrid1 = new DataGrid();

DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DataGrid1);
    }
}
}
```

Error: "The name 'MyReadXml' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always `close` and `dispose` the stream (try using block). restart your appserver (werserver) and see what happen?

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 string MyXmlFile= @"E:\\Programming stuff\\Work\\website\\XMLFile.xml";    
 using(System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml=System.IO.File.OpenRead(MyXmlFile))
  {
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(MyReadXml);
    //Add DataGrid control markup in .aspx.
    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
  }
 }
```

NOTE: If `XMLFile.xml` is placed under the root of `website` then use `Server.MapPath()` method to get absolute file path from virtual path.

```
string MyXmlFile= Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml");
```

If you want to add ASP.NET server control programatically then add `PlaceHolder` control into .aspx file and call the `PlaceControl1.Controls.Add(DataGrid1)` method.

```
string MyXmlFile= @"E:\\Programming stuff\\Work\\website\\XMLFile.xml";    
     using(System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml=System.IO.File.OpenRead(MyXmlFile))
      {
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(MyReadXml);
        DataGrid DataGrid1=new DataGrid();
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DataGrid1);
      }
```

EDIT:

> I still get the error as "MyReadXml does not exist" Did I do anything wrong?

You've terminated the using block. Please remove the semi-colon.

```
using(System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml=new   
     System.IO.FileStream(MyXmlFile,System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: The xml file is indeed placed in the rot of the directory hence followed your suggestion of using Server.MapPath. Also added a placeholder control in the .aspx file. I still get the error as "MyReadXml does not exist" Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: You've terminated the `using` block. Please remove the semi-colon.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. I was getting some kind of a warning saying, possible empty statement but I ignored it. Thank you. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

always close stream after completing work

> > Placing code in a using block ensures that the objects are disposed  as soon as control leaves the block.

```
using(System.IO.FileStream MyReadXml= new System.IO.FileStream(MyXmlFile,System.IO.FileMode.Open));
{
    ds.ReadXml(MyReadXml);

    DataGrid DataGrid1 = new DataGrid();

    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but it is giving me another error:   "The name 'MyReadXml' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @u r using it out of scope, means out of block

Comment: @whatever u want to do ,do only in block

Comment: My knowledge on programming terminology is limited. Could you please tell me what you mean by block? I did the changes to the code as you suggested.

Comment: paste your new all code once again in your question, i want to see whole code

Comment: Edited the original post with the changes. Please let me know your observation.